# Trying to place Python Dictionary into a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Within the code below,
**json_response['data']** returns tweet.fields within query_param.

**json_response['includes']** returns a dictionary with the expansion geo.place_id. It includes keys such as "country", "country_code", "full_name", etc.
**Sample text of what each item returns is at the bottom of this post.**

What I would like to do is have my CSV return the items within the dictionary json_response['includes'] in addition to what it is already returning (aka the dictionary items in json_response['data'] At the moment my CSV returns only items found within json_response['data']

**json_response** is essentially **json_response['data']** and **json_response['includes']** combined.

Any advice is appreciated.
I am working with Twitter API V2, full search functionality.

Image of CSV file:
[image]

```
import requests
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import time

bearer_token = "removed for confidentiality"

search_url = " removed "


query_params = {'query': 'vaccine -is:retweet -is:verified -baby -lotion -shampoo lang:en has:geo place_country:US',
                'tweet.fields':'created_at,lang,text,geo,author_id,id,public_metrics,referenced_tweets',
                'expansions':'geo.place_id', 
                'place.fields':'contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type',
                'user.fields':'description,username',
                'start_time':'2021-01-20T00:00:01.000Z',
                'end_time':'2021-02-17T23:30:00.000Z',
                'max_results':'10'}
#query_params={'query':'(vaccine OR vaccinated) -is:retweet -is:verified -RT -baby -lotion -shampoo&start_time=2021-01-20T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2021-02-20T23:30:00.000Z&max_results=10&tweet.fields=author_id,conversation_id,created_at,geo,id,lang,source,text&expansions=author_id&place.fields=full_name&user.fields=created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,url,username'}

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers


def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params):
    response = requests.request("GET", search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()


def main():
  
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(search_url, headers, query_params)

    new=[] 
    df = pd.json_normalize(json_response['data'])
    print(json_response['includes'].values())
    for k,v in json_response['includes'].items():
        print('k:', k)
        print('v:' , v)
        for item in v:
            print('this is item:', item)
            print('type:', type(item))
            new.append(item)
            
        print('this is new:', new) 

    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(json_response, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

    df.to_csv("icreatedthis.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Sample text for json_response:**

```
{'data': [{'id': '1362182415242956801', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': 'e444ecd51bd16ff3'}, 'text': 'We had a year to figure out vaccine distribution. We’ve now had the vaccine for almost 3 full months. Only having 1 in 20 Americans fully vaccinated is one of the largest societal failures that the history books will be sure to remember ', 'author_id': '4108040657', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:29:30.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'quoted', 'id': '1361907808619356162'}]}, {'id': '1362181538863931393', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 1, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 4, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '36ac79e68ace76e4'}, 'text': 'Thank you @SnowlineJUSD Officer Tim, and Saint Mary’s Apple Valley for making today’s Covid vaccine a great experience! Let’s stay safe, get the vaccine, and get the kids back to school in April!  ', 'author_id': '278693633', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:26:01.000Z'}, {'id': '1362181429682196482', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '13eb8d7f6e12a684'}, 'text': '@sahilkapur @katjoyce74 We’re basically seeing the same thing here in #missouri from @GovParsonMO (if you don’t support you will be last to get the vaccine) these jackass’ dont get to play doctor and screw with peoples. It’s sickening how these guys are “handling” #COVID19 in their states! #COVIDVaccine', 'author_id': '21717525', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:25:35.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362140424450822152'}]}, {'id': '1362181313998979072', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '4b25aded08900fd8'}, 'text': '.@meganmesserly with a great question about cross county line residents trying to get the vaccine if there isn’t an available center in their county. \n\n#COVIDー19', 'author_id': '551324510', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:25:08.000Z'}, {'id': '1362180883545874434', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': 'd35feae19d268b09'}, 'text': "I think of @OPEitsDGR and how he's an essential worker. He needs his vaccine, if he hasn't received it yet, as much as I do. I hate how the distribution is so messed up.", 'author_id': '7260132', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:23:25.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362175413271760899'}]}, {'id': '1362180659092013058', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '8cbcad86e88fd71a'}, 'text': '@KimShaffstall @ChicadeeB I know we take sign ups &amp;assign people to “tiers” based on age&amp;risk factors. When your tier opens we use a lottery to schedule appointment calls. However, it all depends on where you live-some counties receive more vaccine so they’ve been able to open it to more tiers.', 'author_id': '1282793650326577152', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:31.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362177842931466241'}]}, {'id': '1362180628616159233', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '3d533362cdab8107'}, 'text': '@CNNPolitics At his staged &amp; scripted town hall?\n\n@AC360 (the ball less wonder) didn’t have the courage or the backbone to question him on his ridiculous lies. \n\n“We didn’t have the vaccine when I got into office”.\n\nThe 78 year old dementia patient forgot he received the vaccine under Trump!!', 'author_id': '25728613', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:24.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362167202615549952'}]}, {'id': '1362180618595880960', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 4, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '6083b03ae37cd913'}, 'text': '@nytimes There is no data and you aren’t pregnant yet.... Get the vaccine and move on.', 'author_id': '4468794376', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:22.000Z', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362177540467621890'}]}, {'id': '1362180575117860871', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '5b09e0c550ebc298'}, 'text': 'n\n( Sent from EYEWITNESS NEWS WBRE, WYOU )', 'author_id': '98012668', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:11.000Z'}, {'id': '1362180143926673409', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 1, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'geo': {'place_id': '67b98f17fdcf20be'}, 'text': 'A must watch. Vaccine nationalism or “vaccine hoarding” affects all of us. Leaders in powerful countries must step up. None of us will be safe until everyone is safe. @JuanLuisCasCo @HarvardChanDean  @HarvardChanSPH #Hope #Solidarity\n', 'author_id': '1023121267', 'lang': 'en', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:20:29.000Z'}], 'includes': {'places': [{'place_type': 'city', 'id': 'e444ecd51bd16ff3', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-84.710722, 39.052962, -84.3689026, 39.2211137], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Cincinnati', 'full_name': 'Cincinnati, OH'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '36ac79e68ace76e4', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-117.637862, 34.077184, -117.4864431, 34.166156], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Rancho Cucamonga', 'full_name': 'Rancho Cucamonga, CA'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '13eb8d7f6e12a684', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-90.5706573, 38.737756, -90.464711, 38.848337], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'St Charles', 'full_name': 'St Charles, MO'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '4b25aded08900fd8', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-119.953849, 39.350749, -119.700515, 39.674123], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Reno', 'full_name': 'Reno, NV'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': 'd35feae19d268b09', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-118.117365, 33.723095, -118.041655, 33.787561], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Seal Beach', 'full_name': 'Seal Beach, CA'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '8cbcad86e88fd71a', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-84.006198, 42.568064, -83.909455, 42.651203], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Howell', 'full_name': 'Howell, MI'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '3d533362cdab8107', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-117.86894, 33.606077, -117.695781, 33.773387], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Irvine', 'full_name': 'Irvine, CA'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '6083b03ae37cd913', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-123.159583, 44.577589, -123.032415, 44.684678], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Albany', 'full_name': 'Albany, OR'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '5b09e0c550ebc298', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-75.810456, 41.319767, -75.792245, 41.340109], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'West Pittston', 'full_name': 'West Pittston, PA'}, {'place_type': 'city', 'id': '67b98f17fdcf20be', 'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-71.191421, 42.227797, -70.986004, 42.399542], 'properties': {}}, 'name': 'Boston', 'full_name': 'Boston, MA'}]}, 'meta': {'newest_id': '1362182415242956801', 'oldest_id': '1362180143926673409', 'result_count': 10, 'next_token': 'b26v89c19zqg8o3fosns2quc7nhrsukti6r8131acah6l'}}
```

**Sample text for json_response['data']:**

```
[{'author_id': '4108040657', 'text': 'We had a year to figure out vaccine distribution. We’ve now had the vaccine for almost 3 full months. Only having 1 in 20 Americans fully vaccinated is one of the largest societal failures that the history books will be sure to remember ', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'quoted', 'id': '1361907808619356162'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:29:30.000Z', 'id': '1362182415242956801', 'geo': {'place_id': 'e444ecd51bd16ff3'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '278693633', 'text': 'Thank you @SnowlineJUSD Officer Tim, and Saint Mary’s Apple Valley for making today’s Covid vaccine a great experience! Let’s stay safe, get the vaccine, and get the kids back to school in April!  ', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:26:01.000Z', 'id': '1362181538863931393', 'geo': {'place_id': '36ac79e68ace76e4'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 1, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 4, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '21717525', 'text': '@sahilkapur @katjoyce74 We’re basically seeing the same thing here in #missouri from @GovParsonMO (if you don’t support you will be last to get the vaccine) these jackass’ dont get to play doctor and screw with peoples. It’s sickening how these guys are “handling” #COVID19 in their states! #COVIDVaccine', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362140424450822152'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:25:35.000Z', 'id': '1362181429682196482', 'geo': {'place_id': '13eb8d7f6e12a684'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '551324510', 'text': '.@meganmesserly with a great question about cross county line residents trying to get the vaccine if there isn’t an available center in their county. \n\n#COVIDー19', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:25:08.000Z', 'id': '1362181313998979072', 'geo': {'place_id': '4b25aded08900fd8'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '7260132', 'text': "I think of @OPEitsDGR and how he's an essential worker. He needs his vaccine, if he hasn't received it yet, as much as I do. I hate how the distribution is so messed up.", 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362175413271760899'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:23:25.000Z', 'id': '1362180883545874434', 'geo': {'place_id': 'd35feae19d268b09'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '1282793650326577152', 'text': '@KimShaffstall @ChicadeeB I know we take sign ups &amp;assign people to “tiers” based on age&amp;risk factors. When your tier opens we use a lottery to schedule appointment calls. However, it all depends on where you live-some counties receive more vaccine so they’ve been able to open it to more tiers.', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362177842931466241'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:31.000Z', 'id': '1362180659092013058', 'geo': {'place_id': '8cbcad86e88fd71a'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 1, 'like_count': 1, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '25728613', 'text': '@CNNPolitics At his staged &amp; scripted town hall?\n\n@AC360 (the ball less wonder) didn’t have the courage or the backbone to question him on his ridiculous lies. \n\n“We didn’t have the vaccine when I got into office”.\n\nThe 78 year old dementia patient forgot he received the vaccine under Trump!!', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362167202615549952'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:24.000Z', 'id': '1362180628616159233', 'geo': {'place_id': '3d533362cdab8107'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '4468794376', 'text': '@nytimes There is no data and you aren’t pregnant yet.... Get the vaccine and move on.', 'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1362177540467621890'}], 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:22.000Z', 'id': '1362180618595880960', 'geo': {'place_id': '6083b03ae37cd913'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 4, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '98012668', 'text': '\n\n( Sent from EYEWITNESS NEWS WBRE, WYOU )', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:22:11.000Z', 'id': '1362180575117860871', 'geo': {'place_id': '5b09e0c550ebc298'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}, {'author_id': '1023121267', 'text': 'A must watch. Vaccine nationalism or “vaccine hoarding” affects all of us. Leaders in powerful countries must step up. None of us will be safe until everyone is safe. @JuanLuisCasCo @HarvardChanDean  @HarvardChanSPH #Hope #Solidarity\n', 'created_at': '2021-02-17T23:20:29.000Z', 'id': '1362180143926673409', 'geo': {'place_id': '67b98f17fdcf20be'}, 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 1, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'lang': 'en'}]
```

**Sample text for json_response['includes']:**

```
{'places': [{'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Cincinnati', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Cincinnati, OH', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': 'e444ecd51bd16ff3', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-84.710722, 39.052962, -84.3689026, 39.2211137], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Rancho Cucamonga', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Rancho Cucamonga, CA', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '36ac79e68ace76e4', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-117.637862, 34.077184, -117.4864431, 34.166156], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'St Charles', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'St Charles, MO', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '13eb8d7f6e12a684', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-90.5706573, 38.737756, -90.464711, 38.848337], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Reno', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Reno, NV', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '4b25aded08900fd8', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-119.953849, 39.350749, -119.700515, 39.674123], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Seal Beach', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Seal Beach, CA', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': 'd35feae19d268b09', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-118.117365, 33.723095, -118.041655, 33.787561], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Howell', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Howell, MI', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '8cbcad86e88fd71a', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-84.006198, 42.568064, -83.909455, 42.651203], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Irvine', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Irvine, CA', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '3d533362cdab8107', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-117.86894, 33.606077, -117.695781, 33.773387], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Albany', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Albany, OR', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '6083b03ae37cd913', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-123.159583, 44.577589, -123.032415, 44.684678], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'West Pittston', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'West Pittston, PA', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '5b09e0c550ebc298', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-75.810456, 41.319767, -75.792245, 41.340109], 'properties': {}}}, {'country': 'United States', 'name': 'Boston', 'place_type': 'city', 'full_name': 'Boston, MA', 'country_code': 'US', 'id': '67b98f17fdcf20be', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [-71.191421, 42.227797, -70.986004, 42.399542], 'properties': {}}}]}
```

Comment: So, `place_id` in your "data" JSON is a key into the `places` in your "includes".  You need to look for the record where `id` matched your `place_id`.  Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: put your "data" and "includes" in separate DataFrames, then [merge them](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)